# Rails: Understanding Query Model Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have my Ruby on Rails app up and running with 3 scaffolded models. So far so good. Now I'm coding business logic and get a syntax error and can't quite understand how to code a variable.

Details:
    3 models: Document, Employee, and EmpDocument.
    Business rule: Each time a new Document is added create an EmployeeDocument for each Employee
   1.) Loop through Employees
   2.) Cut an EmpDocument.rcd

I get an error on the .Create line, because I don't have my variables coded correctly.
 I've looked through documentation without finding any rules/examples.

```
Document.Model
def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @document.save
    format.html { redirect_to @document, notice: 'Document was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @document }

    # create an EmpDocument record for each employee for this new document
    #@employees = Employee.find(:all)
    Employee.all.each do |employee|
      Empdocument.Create(:document_id => @document.document_id, :employee_id => employee.employee_id, :viewed => '0001-01-01')
    end

  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

here's the error:

"undefined method `document_id' for #"

```
#@employees = Employee.find(:all)
        Employee.all.each do |employee|
          Empdocument.Create(:document_id => @document.document_id, :employee_id => employee.employee_id, :viewed => '0001-01-01')
        end
```

Comment: "I get a syntax error" – Where do you get that syntax error? What does it say? I cannot reproduce that syntax error, the syntax is correct. "I get an error on the .Create line" – What error? What does it say? There is no way that we can help you if you don't even tell us what the problem is. "I don't have my variables coded correctly." – What does that even mean? Define "correctly", please. Please, read up on how to construct a [mcve], [ask], take the [tour], and read the [help].

Comment: Sorry- I couldn't access the app when I posted- here's the error:   #@employees = Employee.find(:all)
        Employee.all.each do |employee|
          Empdocument.Create(:document_id => @document.document_id, :employee_id => employee.employee_id, :viewed => '0001-01-01')
        end (Also updated original post)

Comment: The error looks to indicate that @document does not have method document_id.  Are you sure it isn't @document.id?

Comment: You mention a syntax error in your first paragraph. Where is it? What, *exactly* does it say? I cannot for the life of me figure out why that code would be invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your current requirement, I would encourage you to look into the [after_create](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_create) callback in ActiveModel.

What you can do then in your `Document Model` is

```
after_create :create_emp_documents

def create_emp_documents
 Employeee.all.each do |employee|
   self.empdocuments.create(employee_id: employee.id)
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I remember that callback from my manual- I'll move the code there.

Comment: I would need to pass in the document_id as each new EmpDocument record has the Document-Id in it. I use this file to store when they view it-

create_table "empdocuments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "viewed"
    t.integer  "document_id"
    t.integer  "employee_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["document_id"], name: "index_empdocuments_on_document_id"
    t.index ["employee_id"], name: "index_empdocuments_on_employee_id"
  end

Comment: Within the model, you can pass it's id as self.id,. So document_id => self.id

Comment: in my answer, I assumed you would have an association in the document model `has_many :emp_documents` and hence was calling the create method via the association

Comment: I guess I'm confusing myself. When Empdocument belongs to Document and Employee, does it create it own's keys of document_id and employee_id? And I can't manually use other fields- docname and fullname?
This confusion spills over to my query of which field to use. Thanks in advance!